# Responsive pie chart with react-vis

Tags: javascript, react-vis

I'm reading [the docs on flexible charts](https://github.com/uber/react-vis/blob/master/docs/flexible-plots.md#/examples/charts/responsive-vis) and trying to apply them to a pie chart:

```
import React from 'react'
import { RadialChart, FlexibleXYPlot } from 'react-vis'

const MyChart = ({data}) => (
  <div>
    <FlexibleXYPlot>
      <RadialChart
        data={data}
        colorType="literal"
      />
    </FlexibleXYPlot>
  </div>
)
```

But when rendering this, I get markup like this:

```
<div>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div class="rv-xy-plot " style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the dimensions of the `rv-xy-plot` element are explicitly set to `0px`. What am I doing wrong? How do I create a responsive pie chart?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Comment: @rottweiler: No, I didn't. I can't even remember what I did instead, but I think I ended up going with a different component.

The end result is up at https://bildaregering.nu, so if there's something useful you can look at the code there (or at https://github.com/tomasaschan/bildaregering.nu)

Answer (score 7):

I was recently running into the same problem with a lot of the charts from this package. A work around I found is to use [React-virtualized-auto-sizer](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/AutoSizer.md). Essentially what it does is wrap components that require a width and height around it, then pass the width and height of the parent container (that the auto sizer is in). Here is an example:

```
<div style={{height:'100%',width:'100%'}} className={"mb-4"}>
<AutoSizer>
    {({ height, width }) => (
        <RadialChart
            data={this.state.myData}
            width={width}
            height={height}
            onValueMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver}
            className={"mb-4"}
            labelsAboveChildren={true}
        />
    )}
</AutoSizer>
```

So the autosizer is looking above it at the outer div, figuring out the height and width, then passing it to the chart.

Comment: The link to `React-virtualised` is broken... But I found it [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/AutoSizer.md). That answer should be accepted...

Comment: Worked like charm with the Treemap component too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I can help with this, I had exactly the same problem with a Sankey chart; the documentation makes it look like the `FlexibleXYPlot` will make any chart responsive but that's not the case.

The correct approach is hinted at at the bottom of this page - https://uber.github.io/react-vis/documentation/api-reference/flexible-plots

So for a RadialChart you need to do this:

```
import { RadialChart, makeVisFlexible} from "react-vis";

const FlexRadialChart=makeVisFlexible(RadialChart)
```

and then use the new component that you just created with the responsive code baked in:

```
      <FlexRadialChart
        data={data}
        colorType="literal"
      />
```

Comment: I was struggling with this because the parent containers height was only defined by min-height. To make this work to need to explicitly define height (e.g. 70vh)

Comment: I'm glad my answer pointed you in the right direction - it would also have answered the original question

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem like the library support wrapping radial chart with FlexibleXYPlot or XYPlot for that matter (see issue [Responsive RadialChart "react-vis": "^1.7.7"](https://github.com/uber/react-vis/issues/620), never solved, and I couldn't get it to work), ontop of that RadialChart chart requires the width and height to be sat. 
[image]

Now based on the following issues [FlexibleXYPlot requires height props](https://github.com/uber/react-vis/issues/655) a pr was made to fix this issue but never merged. Based on [Alex Sandiiarov implementation](https://github.com/uber/react-vis/blob/9ec2148529d21024c20b753f9170de2ef93424cb/src/make-vis-flexible.js), the following code can be used to make the pie chart responsive:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ResizeObserver from 'resize-observer-polyfill';
import { RadialChart } from 'react-vis';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            height: 0,
            width: 0
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
    //When mounted set our start size
    this.setSize();
    //Lets observe changes with resize-observer-polyfill
    this.observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => this.setSize());
    //Lets observe our node
        this.observer.observe(this.node);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.observer.disconnect();
    }

    setSize = () => {
        const { height, width } = this.node.getBoundingClientRect();
        this.setState({ height, width });
  };

    render() {
        const { height, width } = this.state;
        return (
            <div
                ref={node => {
                    if (node) {
                        this.node = node;
                    }
                }}
                style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh' }}
            >
                <RadialChart
                    className={'donut-chart-example'}
                    getAngle={d => d.theta}
                    data={[
                        { theta: 2, className: 'custom-class' },
                        { theta: 6 },
                        { theta: 2 },
                        { theta: 3 },
                        { theta: 1 }
                    ]}
                    width={width}
                    height={height}
                    padAngle={0.04}
        colorType="literal"
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Hope this helps you or points you in a useful direction :)

Answer (score 1):

I just add `display: flex` on **parent div** and `flex: 1` on **child div** try this, i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
<div>
  <div style="display: flex; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div class="rv-xy-plot" style="flex: 1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with react hooks, take a look at it:

https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-pie-chart-react-vis-ogor6

If you maybe need it to resize within an element (a `<div>` for example) you might want to use an `useRef` to reference the width/height of the desired element